# new flyway version - sql error

Tags: oracle, ant, oracle11g, flyway

I got an existing project that currently uses flyway-ant, version 2.2.1 for its migrations.

For several reasons I need to use 3.2.1 (repair tables for different line endings).
Unfortunately once I try to setup an empty test database with flyway 3.2.1, I get the following error from Oracle DB:

```
Migration V1_15_1_3__AddCommandParamSDCardLogs.sql failed
---------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 911
Message    : ORA-00911: invalid character
Location   : /Volumes/dev/cs/IdeaProjects/grd/db/src/sql/1.15/V1_15_1_3__AddCommandParam.sql
Line       : 1
Statement  : INSERT INTO T_RD_COMMAND (ID, COMMAND_ID, NAME, DISPLAY_ORDER, DISPLAY_NAME, CREATION_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_TIME) VALUES (SEQ_RD_COMMAND_PARAM.NEXTVAL, (SELECT ID FROM T_RD_COMMANDS WHERE COMMAND_NAME = 'GET_LOGS'), 'fromDate', 1, 'From Date', SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
INSERT INTO T_RD_COMMAND (ID, COMMAND_ID, NAME, DISPLAY_ORDER, DISPLAY_NAME, CREATION_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_TIME) VALUES (SEQ_RD_COMMAND_PARAM.NEXTVAL, (SELECT ID FROM T_RD_COMMANDS WHERE COMMAND_NAME = 'GET_LOGS'), 'toDate', 1, 'To Date', SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
```

Any idea why this happens? Could it be a bug in flyway? Running the migration with flyway 2.2.1 everything's fine, running exactly the same migration with flyway 3.2.1, oracle reports this error.

Btw. it's flyway-ant.

Parsed INSERT statement:

```
INSERT
INTO T_RD_COMMAND
  (
    ID,
    COMMAND_ID,
    NAME,
    DISPLAY_ORDER,
    DISPLAY_NAME,
    CREATION_TIME,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME
  )
  VALUES
  (
    SEQ_RD_COMMAND_PARAM.NEXTVAL,
    (SELECT ID FROM T_RD_COMMANDS WHERE COMMAND_NAME = 'GET_LOGS'
    ),
    'toDate',
    1,
    'To Date',
    SYSDATE,
    SYSDATE
  );
```

Comment: Your insert statement looks fine to me. Can you execute this query against the database? `SELECT ID FROM T_RD_COMMANDS WHERE COMMAND_NAME = 'GET_LOGS'` and attach the results to your question?

Comment: Was a bug ever logged for this?  I'm encountering it as well.  My hypothesis, based on the lines on which this tends to be encountered for me in my scripts, is that it's choking on fromDate/toDate in strings.

Comment: Found a bug that looks to be the one in question, noted in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a parsing issue. Please raise a bug report including the statement in the issue tracker.

Comment: Axel, I noted the issue # in my answer.  May I humbly suggest to prioritize this one?  There seem to be quite a few comments on the bug and it is quite easy to encounter (Inserting the word 'from', for instance).  The workaround is to split up these strings with a concatenation, which of course leaves the migrations a little less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a symptom of this bug:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1010